# Detecting mouse double-click in Flash (AS2)

Tags: flash, mouse, actionscript-2, double-click

Is there a way to detect mouse double-click on a button object using ActionScript 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

To make explicit what the other answers imply, there's no built-in way. You just have to listen for two clicks and decide whether they're close enough together to count as a double, or else use a package that does that, or else use AS3.